# QSqlite changes

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qtsql

My team were previously using Qt 4.3 and are trying to update to the latest release (4.7.2).

Before we were using the qsqlite plugin, but this functionality has been moved into the main QSql component of Qt.

Now that we have upgraded, we're unable to read our old databases. This seems to be because when we created our tables, we created them like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Characters] ([Id] INTEGER NOT NULL ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK, [Project_Id] INTEGER NOT NULL ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK REFERENCES [Projects](Id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON INSERT RESTRICT, [CharacterName] VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK UNIQUE ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK);
```

but `ON INSERT RESTRICT` is no longer valid.

I was able to remove that code and create new tables, but if I do `myQSqlDatabase.tables()` on one of the existing DBs, it returns zero.

I noticed by digging into the Qt code, that the prepare method has:

```
#if (SQLITE_VERSION_NUMBER >= 3003011)
    int res = sqlite3_prepare16_v2(d->access, query.constData(), (query.size() + 1) * sizeof(QChar), &d->stmt, 0);
#else
    int res = sqlite3_prepare16(d->access, query.constData(), (query.size() + 1) * sizeof(QChar), &d->stmt, 0);
#endif
```

and we are entering the first if (`sqlite3_prepare16_v2`).

Should we be defining SQLITE_VERSION_NUMBER somewhere to be lower? Is there something else that we're doing wrong to prevent backwards compatibility?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Liron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlite as downloaded from the authors website comes with a command line program.
If your database isn't compatible you can easily use it to export your data to a text file and load it into your new database.

Comment: Not really an option for us - the application is distributed and there are many copies of the database. We have to ensure that we can read the old DB without any problems.

Comment: I just tried this as a test: Take my old DB, read it in with sqlite.exe and dump to a text file. Create a new DB from that text file. Then dump that out as a text file, and they are equivalent (as expected). It seems that the issue is with the Qt code itself and not with the sqlite code.

Comment: Selected answer because no one else commented. The issue in the Qt code never really got resolved but we worked around it.